# Named range with adress from another named range

Tags: vba, excel

I have code like below, I would like to add named range which adress is connected with other named ranges, below code does not work, thanks in advance for all ideas.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add _
        Name:="somerange", _
        RefersTo:="=Sheet1!Cells(Range("namedrange1").row-5,Range("namedrange2").column)"
```

Comment: Where is "namedrange1"/"namedrange2" defined? Are you sure it's accessible from the active sheet? [it assumes you want the active sheet as you didn't tell the Range function where to pull it from]

Comment: last line is marked in red and it cannot even be executed

Answer (score 2):

With a named range **namedrange1** defined as `RefersTo:=Sheet2!$B$7` with workbook scope and  a named range **namedrange2** defined as `RefersTo:=Sheet3!$D$10` with workbook scope, this will define a new named range named **somerange** with `RefersTo:=Sheet1!$D$2` with workbook scope.

```
With ActiveWorkbook
    With .Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .Cells(Range("namedrange1").Row - 5, Range("namedrange2").Column)
            .Name = "somerange"
        End With
    End With
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Providing namedrange1 is a defined named range you just write it as you would a normal formula:

`ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add "somerange", "=OFFSET(Sheet1!NamedRange1,-5,0,1)"`

In your code you could be referencing two separate sheets -
Sheet1.Cells  and ActiveSheet.Range - if you don't explicitly refer to the sheet name it will use the active sheet.
You're effectively writing:  `"=Sheet1!Cells(ActiveSheet.Range("namedrange1").row-5,ActiveSheet.Range("namedrange2").column)"`

Edit:
Also your code seems to be a combination of formula and VBA code - Sheet1! is used to refer to another sheet in a formula, Cells is a VBA type reference as is .Row and .Column

Edit 2:
You could also use:
`ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add "SomeOtherRange", "=" & Sheet1.Range("NamedRange1").Offset(-5).Resize(1).Address`
but this will hardcode the address - when you check your named ranges it will look something like:  `=Sheet1!$I$5` (if your named range started in cell $I$10).